# JavaScript QR Code scanner that can handle 800+ bytes

Tags: open-source, javascript

I am looking for a open source JavaScript library that can scan large QR codes, preferably via the WebRTC API (so that I don't need Flash, etc.). My target platform is laptop browser (something modern; support for old/IE is a bonus) with a webcam. I haven't been able to get the 800-ish byte QR code that I have to scan properly with `html5-qrcode`, and every open source library I've seen is based on one of these:

- http://dwa012.github.io/html5-qrcode/
- https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode (the base for `html5-qrcode`)

I know what my `html5-qrcode` setup is working, because I've been able to scan smaller QR codes with it with a minimum of having to fiddle around with lining it up with the camera, etc.

I know that the QR code is valid, because I've been able to scan it with these non-free/open scanners, again with little fiddling:

- http://www.themedone.com/qr-scanner-generator/scan.html ($11, but I'm not sure if the license would let me put my project on github)
- https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/scan (no idea what library is in use)
- Some iPad applications (though not all of them that I've tried).

I'm looking for answers of the form:

- Pointers to other libraries that fit the criteria
- Tweaks to `html5-qrcode` that make it Just Work
- Evidence that the libraries used by the above sites are actually suitable for my needs (the www.the-qrcode-generator.com one is pretty nice and I'd use it if I could; the $11 isn't a blocker for the www.themedone.com, but the FAQ didn't really say if I could include the project in an OSS project)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I use zxing scanner compiled by gwt into javascript: https://github.com/jbialobr/JsQRScanner

I was able to scan a 1000+ bytes QR code both on mobile and Windows using Chrome web browser (some browsers don't turn on webcam autofocus on mobile).